# Recursive self-improvement

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Having developed a simple algorithm that demonstrates basic intelligence I am keen to get recursive self-improvement going, the problem I am having is due to my lack of understanding of recursion.

I understand that if I have something that asseses the 'fitness' of the algorithm I am using for improvement (I provide the algorithm with the binary representation of itself) then it uses the basic intelligence it has to produce a new binary algorithm, better than itself).

However what I need to know is this, how can I assess the fitness of the algorithm? I would normally do this

```
if @variable == true
  fitness += 1
end
```

but if fitness is the ability of the algorithm spawned from the algorithm itself, how can I measure this since the spawned algorithm cannot be tested without it spawing a new algorithm itself and so on...

Cheers
Martin

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is almost always a bad idea for algorithms that can be implemented using another approach. Ruby has a number of problems when working at extreme stack depths such as increasing cost of garbage collection, significant stack overhead, and a relatively low ceiling which may result in "stack level too deep" errors.

You would probably be better off creating independent objects that do not share state. Instead of recursing, iterate. Where applicable, use your own self-managed stack such as an Array you `push` and `shift` elements from.

Some example code might be:

```
candidate = stack.shift

if (candidate.fitness > minimum_fitness)
  stack.push(candidate.spawn)
end
```

A method like `spawn` would do whatever magical GA things you need to do and return a *new*, independent instance. This could be augmented to combine with another candidate if required.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self_improve(level)
  return level if level == 100 #this is the brake
  level += 1
  self_improve(level)
end

p self_improve(1) #=>100
```